# How to inherit appropriate class using dynamic binding?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a program which has abstract base `class FILEPARSER` that has two virtual methods `read()` and `print()`.
Two classes inherited from this base class are: `XMLPARSER` and `CONFIGPARSER` that will implement methods.

the main program should accept the type of file "config" or "xml" and inherit the appropriate class for that type?

accepting the options from commandline.

Comment: Do you mean _instantiate_ the correct derived class?

Comment: What's the question? Post some code to show what you've done.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to explicitly construct the right class (pseudocode):

```
FileParser* parser = 0;
ParserType type = //retrieve the type you need
switch( type ) {
case ParserTypeConfig:
    parser = new ConfigParser();
    break;
case ParserTypeXml:
    parser = new XmlParser();
    break;
default:
    //handle error
};

//then at some point you use the created object by calling virtual functions
parser->read(blahblahblah);
parser->print();

// and then at some point you delete the heap-allocated object
delete parser;
parser = 0;
```

of course you should use a smart pointer to handle the heap-allocated object.

Comment: Nice answer to a confusing question.